# How to make "private void backgroundWorker" on xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to make "private void backgroundWorker" on xamarin ?
i have this script ( windows Version ) but i need the same one in android version

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: The BackgroundWorker is supported by Xamarin: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker/. It should have the same API as .NET framework on windows. You'll need to instantiate it and hook up the event though. Are you looking for a background worker example??

Comment: Why do you need to use a background worker? You can have the same features using `Task`, `async`, `await` and `IProgress`.

Comment: @rmc00 yes i need an example

Comment: I don't think we can give you a good answer without more context. Just a very broad question. Here's a link with some examples of your options for async on xamarin.android: http://www.gregshackles.com/using-background-threads-in-mono-for-android-applications/. In particular, pay attention to the AsyncTask section. I really think AsyncTask is the most similar to BackgroundWorker if that's really the best solution in your scenario.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Thread class if you want. First you have to make a class that implement the Runnable interface to that override the run  method.

Example:

```
class PrimeRun implements Runnable {

         PrimeRun() {

         }

         public void run() {
             // compute in background
              . . .
         }
     }
```

Then you have to create a Thread object that use your runnable object.  Like this:

```
PrimeRun p = new PrimeRun();
     new Thread(p).start();
```

If you want to do work while the application is not running"the user is not working with that for example" you have to use the Service :[official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: where i must put the example ?

Comment: in     public class MainActivity : Activity ?

Comment: If you want to executes background code here when user is in this activity you have to do. In general you have to put a thread and start it where you need it.

Comment: Remeber to import the classes and the interface